# Method options for `BooleanMinimize`

Tags: bugs, boolean-computation

I am learning about Boolean Functions and I noticed in the docs for BooleanMinimize they reference a Method option, but don't provide what those options can be.

Is there any more information on how BooleanMinimize works?

Thanks!

Comment: [CASE:5086472] has been reported by me with the reference to this question of you.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. Having looked in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_optimization) and having used trials, I executed in 13.3.1 on Windows 10

```
ClearAll["`*"]; expr = BooleanCountingFunction[{2, 4}, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}]; 
BooleanMinimize[expr, Method -> "QMC"] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{1.50038, (a && b && ! c && ! d && ! e && ! g )...}`

```
ClearAll["`*"]; expr = BooleanCountingFunction[{2, 4}, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}]; 
BooleanMinimize[expr, Method -> "Petrick"] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{1.53905, (a && b && ! c && ! d && ! e && ! g)...}`

```
ClearAll["`*"]; expr = BooleanCountingFunction[{2, 4}, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}]; 
BooleanMinimize[expr, Method -> "Automatic"] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{2.28796, (a && b && ! c && ! d && ! e && ! g)...}`

No syntax error appeared. As we may see , the results are identical, but timings aren't.

Comment: `AbsoluteTiming` is not a good method to compare methods. Use `RepeatedTiming` instead. Then, you will see that `"Petrick"` and `"Automatic"` have practically the same performance.

Comment: @Domen: Thank you for your valuable comment. In this case timings on my comp  are `1.03245, 1.00564, 1.00303 `. `LeafCount`s are decreased from 914 to 773.

Comment: It should be noticed that `BooleanMinimize[expr, Method -> ""] // AbsoluteTiming` and `BooleanMinimize[expr, Method -> "QQQQQ"] // AbsoluteTiming` produce the same as `Method->"Automatic"`.